# Waveshare SIM7600E-H no internet connection

Tags: modules, hat

I don't know why i'm not able to connect to the internet with my HAT. Maybe i'm doing the connection check wrong, because i'm always getting `Error` when i test a ftp connection.

I'm getting following networks when i send the command  `AT+COPS=?`:

> (1,"Swisscom","Swisscom","22801",7),(2,"Wingo","Wingo","22801",2),(1,"Swisscom","Swisscom","22801",0),(1,"Salt","Salt","22803",2),(3,"Sunrise","Sunrise","22802",7),(3,"Sunrise","Sunrise","22802",0),(3,"Sunrise","Sunrise","22802",2),(1,"Salt","Salt","22803",7),(1,"Salt","Salt","22803",0),,(0,1,2,3,4,5),(0,1,2)

My carrier is Wingo, so i sent the command:

```
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","Wingo"
```

After that i sent `ATD*99***1#` and get the message

> CONNECT 115200

But then it freezes and i can't exit with `CTRL+A, k, y`.

I'm on macOS and for the serial connection i'm using https://www.decisivetactics.com/products/serial/

Informations:

- `AT+COPS?` returns `0,0,"Wingo Wingo",2`
- Send SMS works
- Phone call works
- `AT+CSQ` returns the message `+CSQ: 14,99`

Can someone help me? What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands are extensions of the analog modem controls commands. `ATD` means to dial. If the answer is `CONNECT`, then the modem is connected. That means that after you see the `CONNECT` message, everything you type or otherwise send to the modem goes to the other side, and you get whatever the other side sends, which here is nothing.

To disconnect, you have to wait for a second (or more), then type `+++` without too much delay. Then you should be back to command mode. After that, you can use the command `ATH` for hangup to disconnect.

If you want to have an internet connection, you probably need to run `pppd` on the serial line after you connect.

Comment: Ah okay, now i understand. Thank's a lot RalfFriedl :).

Comment: @RalfFriedl, many thanks for your very detailed explanation and instruction.  You save newbies' much time troubleshooting.

Comment: @Maisen1886， Your question is good, giving just enough details, and highlighting critical parts in yellow.  I am glad that your question leads to helpful explanation and instructions.  Here I learnt methods and skills specific to your problem, but also to general situations as well.  Cheers! :)